# Creating point feature class template with specific distance between them that generates points in every projection,keeping the same metrical distance

Tags: arcgis-pro, geojson, gml

I am working on digitizing airport lights in ArcGIS Pro. I would like to create a point feature class representing airport lights that could serve as a standard template for different airports around the world.

The points (lights) are placed in a given distance from each other according to a standard system. The main idea is to be able to use these points for different airports in different projections and the distance between them does not change although we move from one UTM zone to another. No need to have exact coordinates because the points will be moved manually to its right location.

I need a solution on how to make this more automated, and we don’t need to create every time a new light system for every individual projections or worse case we create light systems for every UTM zone but automatically, using a template. The initial idea was to create the points in a local Cartesian coordinate system (like in CAD, using threshold lights as the start 0 point). Is there any tool or scrip that will generate points according to a Cartesian schema into different projections? Any other idea on how this task could be accomplished?

Comment: Please decide regarding the software you want to use, other your question can be closed as too broad.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use ArcGis pro. Would appreciate any hint.